# How to add circularprogressindicator before run flutter app

Tags: flutter, navigator, progress-indicator

I'm new to flutter. I'm trying to build register and login app. I need to make circularprogressindicator before running app . it worked fine before I added a Navigator.
after I addedd Navigator it not worked. Can anyone help me please.

```
class Loading extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoadingState createState() => _LoadingState();
}

class _LoadingState extends State<Loading> {
  void _loadUserInfo() async {
    String token = await getToken();
    if (token == '') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()), (route) => false);
    } else {
      ApiResponse response = await getUserDetails();
      if (response.error == null) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Home()), (route) => false);
      } else if (response.error == unauthorized) {
        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>Login()), (route) => false);
      } else {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content : Text('${response.error}'),
        ));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _loadUserInfo();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you are not disabling the progress indicator after initalization. In your case a futurebuilder would make more sense in order to check for different Progress Stages

Comment: Are you sure you called this widget in your MyApp Class in main?.

Comment: @mbakabilal yes and login page appear normal but progress indicator not shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current code in initstate you have called a method that checks for the token. I assume that's from shared preferences . When you first install the app it would give you an empty string(assuming again). Then the first condition check is that if its empty you are navigating to login page.

```
 String token = await getToken();
    if (token == '') {
      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()), (route) => false);
    }
```

To force to display the progress indicator you can add a future delayed before navigating like

```
 String token = await getToken();
    if (token == '') {
     Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:4), (){
         Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Login()), (route) => false);
     });
     
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `Future` function

```
Future _loadUserInfo() async {}
```

and in the body use like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: _loadUserInfo(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        return Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.white,
          child: const Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

this will show indicator but i suggest you to work with `snapshot`

```
if (snapshot.hasError) {
// here indicator should be       
}else{ 
// in the else you need to show login 
}
```

- [future class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html)
- [read on medium](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/explore-futures-in-flutter-50ea5b91fc2#:%7E:text=To%20perform%20such%20tasks%20in,will%20Explore%20Futures%20In%20Flutter.)

research about future to read more

Comment: @xnor try this.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding. But where do I put FutureBuilder in the code

Comment: instead of container or wrap container with futurebuilder

Comment: @mohammadesmaili sorry but it not work.